# How to have method called everytime variable increases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, livewires

I'm trying to add some difficulty in "game". Basically I want to call method to increase speed of a sprite everytime players score is multiply of 100 (it should happen on 100, 200, etc.).

I'm using pygame and livewires packages.

How I handled it was by using range like:

```
if self.score.value in range(0, 10000+1, 100):
                pizza.update_speed()
```

and update method just increases speed:

```
def update_speed(self):
        Pizza.speed += 0.25
```

So... it works but I am sure that it is not elegant and there is a better way of doing it.
How should I code it so I can check the score "infinitely" and in a proper way?

Comment: Make `speed` a `property` of the `Pizza` class.

Comment: I could include whole code but speed is a property of Pizza class what I want to achievie is to check score everytime it is 100, 200 etc and do it "without an end".

Comment: In that case, in the setter method of the `speed` property, use the `%` operator to detect when the score value is a whole multiple of 100 (similar to what's in @Rabbid76's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the remainder (`%`) of the division of `self.score.value` and 100 is 0:

```
if self.score.value % 100 == 0:
    pizza.update_speed()
```